# Filtering dataframe by date

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I am new to r and am trying to figure out how to filter by data set by including data from the months of 01 to 08 but my dataset has multiple years of data contained within it. How would I do this?

I was thinking to us the filter function and then between certain dates but that would require me doing this for the 9 years separately. Could it be done easier?

Comment: please share your data. You can use `dput`. paste the output of `dput(your_data)`. Please share an example with the desired output, and the code for whatever you tried

Comment: that said, we can use the `lubridate` package for handling dates. In the following example, `lubridate::month` correctly extracs `8` from a vector of dates: `lubridate::month(mdy(c("08/17/2022", "08/30/1975"))) - output : 8   8`

Comment: Combining dandrews example data and  @GuedesBF `lubridate::month` we could do: `df <- tibble(date=seq.Date(from = as.Date('01/01/10', format='%m/%d/%y'), to=as.Date('12/31/18', format='%m/%d/%y'), by='day'),  variable=sample(seq(1,100,1),length(date),replace = T))

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  mutate(day = day(date), 
         month = month(date), 
         year = year(date)
         ) %>% 
  filter(month == 8)`

Comment: Yes, TarJae, with a minor correction: last function call should be `filter(month<8)` for the desired use case

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to handle this. In the future please provide a minimal reproducible example and some code you have tried.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Reproducible data
df <- tibble(date=seq.Date(from = as.Date('01/01/10',
                                          format='%m/%d/%y'),
                           to=as.Date('12/31/18',
                                      format='%m/%d/%y'),
                           by='day'),
             variable=sample(seq(1,100,1),length(date),replace = T))
df

df %>% 
  mutate(month=as.numeric(substr(date,6,7))) %>% 
  filter(month<=8)
```

Here's a way to do it with lubridate per the good suggestions in the comments.

```
library(lubridate) 
df %>%   
  mutate(day = day(date),
         month = month(date),
         year = year(date)) %>% 
  filter(month <= 8)
```

Comment: I think it may be much better to use a proper date handling function like lubridate::month, then extracting character scalars by position or substring.

Comment: @AmeliaFran13 the idea here for either piece of code is to extract the month as a numeric variable (new column) and then filter those values rather than having to specify all of the dates using the boolean operator `|` which I think is what you were doing when you asked if there was a better way

Comment: We do not even need to extract the date into three variables. `df %>% filter(month(date)<8))` is enough

Comment: @GuedesBF Yes, I think that (which I stripped from the comments) was just to provide the example for all three variables